# Download files from bytea column in postgresql with python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, bytea

##### Hi,

Can I download a file from my database from a column type bytea in python? 
I'm trying to do with the psycopg2, I upload a .txt file but when I tried to retrieved it to my local machine, it just save a .txt file with non-readable data, the txt file starts like this *"U0ZUUCBhZGRy...."* so looks like bytes info, the same as the DB saves.

An screenshot of the DB in dbeaver [example_dbeaver_column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2ZZI.png)

This is the code I used.

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, 
                                  host=host, 
                                  port=port,
                                  user=user, 
                                  password=password)
    
# get cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "select c.file from my_table t where t.file_name = 'credentials.txt'"
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
file_binary=data[0][0].tobytes()
with open('my_text.txt','wb') as file:
    file.write(file_binary)
```

Any ideas how I can solve this problem? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks to me like whatever you used to save the content in a `bytea` column encoded it into base64.  When you do your DBeaver query, you should see the original text file that you uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
In postgre it's encoded in base64 so I need to decoded with base64 library.

```
import base64 
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, 
                                  host=host, 
                                  port=port,
                                  user=user, 
                                  password=password)
    
# get cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "select c.file from my_table t where t.file_name = 'credentials.txt'"
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
file_binary=data[0][0].tobytes()
with open('my_text.txt','wb') as file:
    file.write(base64.b64decode(file_binary))
```